# How to extract a smooth skeleton from an image

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I have some font character images of fixed size as shown under the Input image sample. I want to extract the character skeleton (single-pixel wide). I have tried various ways as shown below but the outputs are all different and not smooth. I thought that the one-pixel-wide skeleton will be smooth (pixels not breaking and no noise pixels). Is there a better way to do this? If no which one is the best among these three?

**Input image sample**

[image]

**1) Example**

```
from skimage import img_as_bool, io, color, morphology
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = img_as_bool(color.rgb2gray(io.imread('image.jpeg')))
out = morphology.medial_axis(image)

f, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax0.imshow(image, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
ax1.imshow(out, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

**Output1**

[image]

**2) Example**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import mahotas as mh
import numpy as np

image = Image.new("RGBA", (600,150), (255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
fontsize = 150
font = ImageFont.truetype("font.TTF", fontsize)
txt = '가'
draw.text((30, 5), txt, (0,0,0), font=font)
img = image.resize((188,45), Image.ANTIALIAS)
print(type(img))
plt.imshow(img)

img = np.array(img)
im = img[:,0:50,0]
im = im < 128
skel = mh.thin(im)
noholes = mh.morph.close_holes(skel)
plt.subplot(311)
plt.imshow(im)
plt.subplot(312)
plt.imshow(skel)
```

**Output2**

[image]

**3) Example**

```
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage import draw
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import os

# load image from file
img_fname='D:\Ammar Data\Debbie_laptop_data\Ammar\sslab-deeplearning\GAN models\sslab_GAN\skeleton\hangul_1.jpeg' 
image=imread(img_fname)

# Change RGB color to gray 
image=rgb2gray(image)

# Change gray image to binary
image=np.where(image>np.mean(image),1.0,0.0)

# perform skeletonization
skeleton = skeletonize(image)

plt.imshow(skeleton)
```

**output3**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine but you may need to change the way you are converting the image to binary. Also, to avoid the noisy looking output, you can apply `binary_closing` to your skeleton image. Take a look at the below code -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import img_as_bool
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize, binary_closing


im = img_as_bool(rgb2gray(imread('0jQjL.jpg')))
out = binary_closing(skeletonize(im))

f, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax0.imshow(im, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
ax1.imshow(out, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Your two sample images gave me the below output -

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
To avoid the precision loss when converting the image to bool, you can also binarize the image using one of the available [thresholding algorithms](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/auto_examples/xx_applications/plot_thresholding.html). I prefer otsu's.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize, binary_closing

def get_binary(img):    
    thresh = threshold_otsu(img)
    binary = img > thresh
    return binary

im = get_binary(rgb2gray(imread('Snip20190410_9.png')))
out = binary_closing(skeletonize(im))

f, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax0.imshow(im, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
ax1.imshow(out, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Comment: OK, Thanks. BTW, when I run this code using skeletonize(), skeletonize_3d() or thin() i get this warning "C:\Users\ammar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py:122: UserWarning: Possible precision loss when converting from uint8 to bool
  .format(dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj_out))". Is their a way to avoid this loss? and how can I choose the best skeleton out of these three functions mentioned above?

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan You can avoid the loss using an appropriate thresholding algorithm. I have updated my answer to fix the precision loss warning. The best skeleton of the three would be the one which gives you the best result for most of your sample images.

Comment: So, identifying the best will be by just visualizing or we have some technical measure?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any technical measure for the accuracy of skeletonization. You will have to rely on visual inspection only.